# Angularjs factory to retrieve api

Tags: angularjs

This is how my factory look like:

```
  myApp.factory('displayAll', function($http){


var service = {};
var aaudit = [];
service.callAudit = function () {
    $http.get(AuditUrl).then(function(response) {
        aaudit = response.data.SrchResults;
        aaudit.splice(0,1);
        console.log(aaudit)
        return aaudit;
    });

}


return service;

});
```

I am trying to get the aaudit information to a controller, how can i do that? Cause the examples i see are all just retrieving the url alone. Is it possible to do it the way I am doing it?

The controller :

```
    var CategoryExhibit = displayAll.callExhibit()
      .then(function (response) {
        $scope.exhibitions = response.data.SrchResults;
        $scope.exhibitions.splice(0,1);
      }, function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

It works this way, but i am trying to shift the whole chunk of code into factory so that i could use it on other controller as well

Update:

```
      service.callAudit = function () {
        $http.get(AuditUrl).then(function(data) {
        aaudit = response.data.SrchResults;
        aaudit.splice(0,1);
        console.log(aaudit)
        return aaudit;
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the promise from the service `return $http.get()`

Here's a working example

```js
angular.module("app",[]).controller("myCtrl",function($scope, auditService){

$scope.exhibitions = {};
auditService.callAudit()
      .then(function (response) {
        $scope.exhibitions = response;
      }, function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });

}).factory('auditService', function($http){

var service = {};
var aaudit = [];
service.callAudit = function () {
    return $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos').then(function(response) {
        aaudit = response.data;
        console.log(aaudit.splice(0,1))
        return aaudit.splice(0,1);
    });

}
return service;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
{{exhibitions}}
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to tell me how to write the code in the controller to retrieve it?

Comment: And would this be returning the data that is stored in aaudit or is it just returning the url

Comment: @HangulSR The displayAll.callExhibit() will return a promise, so you need to apply the .then(function(data)) to that. The data will then contain what you returned from the service, in this case the "return aaudit;"

Comment: I am sorry but is it possible for you to elaborate on it? I am rather new to angularjs. How do i return the aaudit result? Do i change the (response) to (data) ? @Marcus Höglund

Comment: @HangulSR updated the answer with a mock-json implementation

Comment: Thank you so so so so so so much for the help! @Marcus Höglund

Comment: @HangulSR NP, happy to help :)